# SSD not found during installation

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

While I was trying to install Ubuntu to my hard drive (which is an SSD, maybe 2 years old) and it just can't seem to locate the drive as if it doesn't exist. I tried rebooting multiple times, unplugging all the other drives, etc., but nothing seems to help. I'd really like a dual boot as I'm getting sick of Windows.

- KINGSTON SNV425S264GB
- Firmware: C091
- SSD 64GB 110/200 VDTb 2.5 KIN
- driver version; 5.1.2535.0

```
[    4.986663] [drm]     DFP3: INTERNAL_UNIPHY 
[    4.986706] [drm]    CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1 
[    5.016547] firewire_ohci: Added fw-ohci device 0000:0c:03.0, OHCI v1.10, 4 IR + 8 IT contexts, quirks 0x11 
[  5.284075] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300) 
[    5.288087] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300) 
[    5.463792] [drm] Radeon display connector DP-1: No monitor connected or invalid EDID 
[ 5.515756] firewire_core: created device fw0: GUID 001e8c0000c81348, S400 
[    5.568992] [drm] Radeon display connector HDMI-A-1: Found valid EDID 
[    5.622496] [drm] Radeon display connector DVI-I-1: Found valid EDID 
[    5.622583] [drm] Internal thermal controller with fan control 
[    5.622698] [drm] radeon: power management initialized 
[    5.678152] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas 
[   5.678793] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver... 
[    5.678939] scsi8 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0 
[    5.679053] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage 
[    5.679100] USB Mass Storage support registered. 
[    5.747413] usb 1-1.4: new high speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd 
[    5.821222] [drm] fb mappable at 0xE0141000 
[   5.821266] [drm] vram apper at 0xE0000000 
[    5.821308] [drm] size 8294400 
[    5.821350] [drm] fb depth is 24 
[    5.821391] [drm]    pitch is 7680 
[    5.821463] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device 
[    5.849482] scsi9 : usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0 
[    5.919314] usb 1-1.5: new full speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd 
[   6.013337] hub 1-1.5:1.0: USB hub found 
[    6.013522] hub 1-1.5:1.0: 3 ports detected 
[    6.083036] usb 1-1.6: new full speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd 
[    6.182767] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input2 
[    6.182844] generic-usb 0003:046D:C52B.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0 
[    6.184851] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input3 
[    6.185103] generic-usb 0003:046D:C52B.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1 
[    6.187872] generic-usb 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input2 
[    6.187895] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid 
[    6.187896] usbhid: USB HID core driver 
[    6.250680] usb 2-1.1: new high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd 
[    6.259316] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67 
[    6.263262] fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device 
[    6.263263] drm: registered panic notifier 
[    6.263298] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.10.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0 
[6.630088] usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd 
[    6.684730] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Compact Flash 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS 
[    6.691228] scsi 8:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic- SM/xD-Picture    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS 
[    6.697692] scsi 8:0:0:2: Direct-Access     Generic- SD/MMC           1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS 
[    6.704183] scsi 8:0:0:3: Direct-Access     Generic- MS/MS-Pro        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS 
[    6.723704] scsi10 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0 
[    6.775943] Btrfs loaded 
[    6.779953] xor: automatically using best checksumming function: generic_sse 
[   6.793807] usb 2-1.3: new low speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd 
[    6.797638]    generic_sse: 12807.000 MB/sec 
[    6.797643] xor: using function: generic_sse (12807.000 MB/sec) 
[    6.799018] device-mapper: dm-raid45: initialized v0.2594b 
[    6.897689] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/input/input4 
[    6.897764] generic-usb 0003:046D:C508.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3/input0 
[  6.969663] usb 2-1.4: new high speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd 
[    7.063246] scsi11 : usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0 
[    7.121527] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0 
[    7.121619] sd 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0 
[    7.121806] sd 8:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0 
[    7.121934] sd 8:0:0:3: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0 
[    7.137287] usb 2-1.5: new high speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd 
[    7.143640] sd 8:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk 
[    7.146229] sd 8:0:0:2: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk 
[    7.147380] sd 8:0:0:3: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk 
[    7.152561] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk 
[    7.235935] scsi12 : usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0 
[   7.309004] usb 2-1.7: new low speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd 
[    7.412950] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.0/input/input5 
[    7.413019] logitech 0003:046D:C517.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.7/input0 
[    7.418375] logitech 0003:046D:C517.0006: fixing up Logitech keyboard report descriptor 
[    7.418716] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.1/input/input6 
[    7.418826] logitech 0003:046D:C517.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.7/input1 
[    7.480908] usb 2-1.8: new high speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd 
[    7.590643] scsi13 : usb-storage 2-1.8:1.0 
[    7.660568] usb 1-1.5.1: new full speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd 
[    7.754942] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD10 TPVT-00U4RT1     01.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS 
[    7.756787] input: HID 0a5c:4502 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.1/1-1.5.1:1.0/input/input7 
[    7.756865] generic-usb 0003:0A5C:4502.0007: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [HID 0a5c:4502] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1/input0 
[   7.836358] usb 1-1.5.2: new full speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd 
[    7.934097] input: HID 0a5c:4503 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2/1-1.5.2:1.0/input/input8 
[    7.934177] generic-usb 0003:0A5C:4503.0008: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [HID 0a5c:4503] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.2/input0 
[   8.008059] usb 1-1.5.3: new full speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd 
[    8.061332] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 070B 1032 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4 
[    8.062290] scsi 11:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1032 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4 
[   8.236813] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS 
[    8.592581] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Iomega E xternal HD       0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4 
[    8.882015] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  HM641JI               PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS 
[    8.910861] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0 
[   8.911069] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0 
[    8.911196] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0 
[    8.911352] scsi 11:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 13 
[    8.911591] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg9 type 0 
[    8.911852] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] 975400960 512-byte logical blocks: (499 GB/465 GiB) 
[   8.911860] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg10 type 0 
[    8.912718] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB) 
[    8.912722] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] 31375360 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB) 
[    8.913418] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off 
[    8.913422] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00 
[    8.913594] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off 
[   8.913598] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 23 00 10 00 
[    8.913718] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB) 
[    8.913964] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page present 
[   8.913966] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    8.914586] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off 
[    8.914590] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00 
[    8.915335] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present 
[    8.915337] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    8.915463] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] No Caching mode page present 
[    8.915465] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    8.917470] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present 
[    8.917475] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    8.919147] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] Write Protect is off 
[    8.919150] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] Mode Sense: 38 00 00 00 
[    8.919603] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] No Caching mode page present 
[    8.919608] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    8.920274]  sdg: sdg1 
[    8.925532] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] No Caching mode page present 
[    8.925538] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    8.927768] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] No Caching mode page present 
[    8.927774] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    8.927779] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk 
[    8.939473] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] No Caching mode page present 
[    8.939479] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    8.959174]  sdi: sdi1 
[    8.983309] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] No Caching mode page present 
[    8.983315] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    8.983320] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI disk 
[    9.212316]  sdf: sdf1 
[    9.230266] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present 
[    9.230268] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[    9.230270] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk 
[   11.610888] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] 1250263728 512-byte logical blocks: (640 GB/596 GiB) 
[   11.611755] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off 
[   11.611772] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00 
[   11.612565] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present 
[   11.612581] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[   11.615198] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present 
[   11.615215] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[   11.615786]  sde: sde1 
[   11.640438] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present 
[   11.640462] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[   11.640484] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk 
[   11.914038] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page present 
[   11.914062] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[   11.914663]  sdh: 
[   11.916917] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page present 
[   11.916946] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[   11.916974] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk 
[   11.917312] ses 11:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device 
[   14.221690] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher 
[   21.855658] udevd[1656]: starting version 173 
[  21.991038] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16 
[   21.991056] NET: Registered protocol family 31 
[   21.991058] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized 
[   21.991060] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized 
[   21.991061] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized 
[21.991894] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized 
[   22.051657] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain 
[  22.073893] ATK0110 ATK0110:00: EC enabled 
[   22.076965] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6 
[   22.077088] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb 
[   22.138897] EDAC MC: Ver:2.1.0 
[   22.160301] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to 'i7core_edac.c' 'i7 core #0': DEV 0000:3f:03.0 
[   22.160319] EDAC PCI0: Giving out device to module 'i7core_edac' controller 'EDAC PCI controller': DEV '0000:3f:03.0' (POLLED) 
[   22.160322] EDAC i7core: Driver loaded. 
[  22.208906] Linux video capture interface: v2.00 
[   22.236678] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device  (046d:081b) 
[   22.251510] input: UVC Camera (046d:081b) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input9 
[   22.251622] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo 
[  22.251624] USB Video Class driver (v1.1.0) 
[   22.325240] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated: 
[   22.325242] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp) 
[  22.325244] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   22.325246] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   22.325248] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[  22.325249] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   22.325251] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   22.363308] IR NEC protocol handler initialized 
[   22.377463] saa7130/34: v4l2 driver version0.2.16 loaded 
[   22.377513] saa7134 0000:0c:01.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16 
[   22.377518] saa7133[0]: found at 0000:0c:01.0, rev: 209, irq: 16, latency: 64, mmio: 0xf7fff800 
[  22.377524] saa7133[0]: subsystem: 1043:4845, board: ASUS TV-FM 7135 [card=53,autodetected] 
[   22.377547] saa7133[0]: board init: gpio is 0 
[   22.386031] IR RC5(x) protocol handler initialized 
[   22.400233] IR RC6 protocol handler initialized 
[   22.423367] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22 
[  22.423412] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X 
[   22.423432] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64 
[   22.424177] IR JVC protocol handler initialized 
[   22.427738] IR Sony protocol handler initialized 
[   22.456473] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 249  
[   22.465289] IR LIRC bridge handler initialized 
[   22.477705] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17 
[   22.477827] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: irq 62 for MSI/MSI-X 
[   22.477847] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: setting latency timer to 64 
[   22.503770] HDMI status: Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0 
[   22.503847] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input10 
[  22.528561] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 00: 43 10 45 48 54 20 1c 00 43 43 a9 1c 55 d2 b2 92 
[   22.528567] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 10: 00 ff e2 0f ff 20 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528572] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 20: 01 40 01 02 03 01 01 03 08 ff 00 88 ff ff ff ff 
[  22.528578] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 30: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528583] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 40: ff 22 00 c2 96 ff 02 30 15 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528588] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 50: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[  22.528593] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 60: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528598] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 70: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528603] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 80: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[  22.528608] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 90: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528613] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528618] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[  22.528623] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom c0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528628] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom d0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528633] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[  22.528638] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
[   22.528645] saa7133[0]: P7131 analog only, using entry of ASUSTeK P7131 Analog 
[   22.580475] Registered IR keymap rc-asus-pc39 
[   22.580538] input: saa7134 IR (ASUSTeK P7131 Analo as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:0c:01.0/rc/rc0/input11 
[  22.580580] rc0: saa7134 IR (ASUSTeK P7131 Analo as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:0c:01.0/rc/rc0 
[   22.580675] rc rc0: lirc_dev: driver ir-lirc-codec (saa7134) registered at minor = 0 
[   22.591564] i2c-core: driver [tuner] using legacy suspend method 
[ 22.591566] i2c-core: driver [tuner] using legacy resume method 
[   22.644511] tuner 9-004b: Tuner -1 found with type(s) Radio TV. 
[   22.739986] init: failsafe main process (2041) killed by TERM signal 
[   22.740309] init: alsa-restore main process (2339) terminated with status 99 
[   22.744161] tda829x 9-004b: setting tuner address to 61 
[22.750445] r8169 0000:05:00.0: eth0: link down 
[   22.751189] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[   22.803523] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down 
[   22.803529] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down 
[   22.804362] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready 
[   22.820043] tda829x 9-004b: type set to tda8290+75a 
[   22.908087] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized 
[   22.908092] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized 
[   22.908093] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver1.11 
[   22.914275] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 
[   22.914278] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast 
[   23.407602] 3:3:1: cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x86 
[   23.555851] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio 
[   24.456867] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link up 
[   24.457387] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready 
[   26.610335] saa7133[0]: registered device video1 [v4l2] 
[   26.610382] saa7133[0]: registered device vbi0 
[  26.610412] saa7133[0]: registered device radio0 
[   26.610580] ath9k 0000:0c:02.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17 
[  26.619689] saa7134 ALSA driver for DMA sound loaded 
[   26.619706] saa7133[0]/alsa: saa7133[0] at 0xf7fff800 irq 16 registered as card -2 
[   27.465622] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   27.470360] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   28.170129] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x809c 
[   28.170131] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code 
[   28.170132] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search 
[   28.170133] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52 
[  28.170134] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN 
[   28.170135] ath: Regpair used: 0x52 
[   28.170138] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[ 28.170140] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170141] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170143] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[  28.170144] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170146] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170148] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170149] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170151] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170153] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170154] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170156] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170157] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170159] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170160] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170162] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170164] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170165] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170167] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170169] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170170] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.170172] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.170173] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2467 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel 
[   28.170175] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2472 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel 
[  28.170176] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel 
[   28.172672] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172674] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172677] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172679] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172681] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172684] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172685] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172688] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172690] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172693] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172694] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172697] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172698] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172700] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172701] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172703] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172705] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172706] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172708] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172710] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172711] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172713] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172714] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172716] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172717] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172719] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.172721] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2484 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.172723] cfg80211: 2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.181814] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'ath9k_rate_control' 
[   28.182313] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: CN 
[   28.182369] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0 
[   28.182373] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9280 Rev:2 mem=0xffffc90001b20000, irq=17 
[   28.184804] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.184807] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.184809] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.184812] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.184814] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.184816] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.184818] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.184821] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.184823] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule: 
[   28.184825] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz)- 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[   28.184871] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm) 
[  28.237872] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready 
[   28.347718] lp: driver loaded but no devices found 
[   28.366220] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver 
[   28.467369] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   29.469668] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   29.728231] cfg80211: Found new beacon on frequency: 2472 MHz (Ch 13) on phy0 
[   30.468086] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   31.467038] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[  32.464915] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   33.463344] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   34.461643] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   34.777120] eth1: no IPv6 routers present 
[   35.460069] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   36.458651] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   37.456851] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   38.455273] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   39.453753] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[  40.452140] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   41.450457] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   42.449083] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   43.447342] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[   44.445676] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[  44.587162] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536 
[   44.632652] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled 
[   44.633366] SGI XFS Quota Management subsystem 
[   45.444276] 3:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86 
[ 101.004203] NTFS driver 2.1.30 [Flags: R/O MODULE]. 
[  101.035285] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered. 
[  289.523592] CE: hpet increased min_delta_ns to 20113 nsec 
[  647.448669] usb 2-1.8: USB disconnect, device number 9 
[  648.982277] usb 2-1.7: USB disconnect, device number 8 
[  657.672724] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 5 
[ 658.686681] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down 
[  658.695127] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 6 
[  660.947609] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link up 
[  662.529012] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4 
[  664.660117] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down 
[ 666.223675] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link up 
[  768.544851] usb 2-1.7: new low speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd 
[ 768.645799] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.0/input/input12 
[  768.645934] logitech 0003:046D:C517.0009: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.7/input0 
[  768.651054] logitech 0003:046D:C517.000A: fixing up Logitech keyboard report descriptor 
[  768.651724] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.1/input/input13 
[  768.651935] logitech 0003:046D:C517.000A: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.7/input1 
[  773.788397] usb 2-1.1: reset high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd 
[  774.102287] snd-usb-audio 2-1.1:1.2: no reset_resume for driver snd-usb-audio? 
[  774.102293] snd-usb-audio 2-1.1:1.3: no reset_resume for driver snd-usb-audio?
```

Comment: i checked again, and my other internal drive (regular hard drive 1TB samsung) couldn't be found either, could it be the drivers of the sata controller on my motherboard?

Comment: 64 Gigabytes is a bit small for a good dual-boot. I recommend using at least a 240GB SSD (I'm using 480GB). And if there is less than 10GB room left over, it may not even accept Lubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem had something to do with the hardware of my motherboard, it uses a marvell adapter for an addition 3 sata ports. The devices that were plugged into these ports weren't found by ubuntu, once i plugged them into the normal sata ports provided on my motherboard the devices were found. 
Thanks for all the help anyways.