# SSD comes and goes

Tags: boot, mount, ssd, motherboard

I have a Gigabyte Aorus Master Z390 motherboard with 3 SSD slots, all populated.  Occasionally one of the SSD's doesn't show up after reboot.  I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  How can I diagnose this?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1275785/778232 . Was there a recent update?

Comment: Try reseating the cables to the SSD if 2.5" SSD, if m.2 reseat the SSD. This looks like a hardware problem.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and firmware on all SSDs?

Comment: No.  I started with Ubuntu 19 and it got auto-upgraded to 20.04. How do I update UEFI and firmware on an SSD?

Comment: Also I agree this is very similar to 778232 question, but that is also unanswered.

Comment: @LarsEricson " but that is also unanswered". Regrettably so. There are far more accounts of spurious bugs with USB connections a least since 18.04.

Comment: This is not USB, the SSD is an M.2 stick plugged into my motherboard.